# how can i take the derivative of the softmax output in back-prop

Tags: java, machine-learning, backpropagation, derivative, softmax

So I am new to ML and trying to make a simple "library" so I can learn more about neural networks.

My question:
According to my understanding I have to take the derivative of each layer according to their activation function so I can calculate their deltas and adjust their weights etc...

For ReLU, sigmoid, tanh, it's super simple to implement them in Java (which is the language I am using BTW)

But to go from output to the input I have to start from (obviously) the output which has an activation function of softmax.

So do I have to take the derivative of the output layer as well or does it just apply to every other layer?

If I do have to get the derivative how can I implement the derivative that in Java?
Thanks.

I have read a lot of pages with the explanation of the derivative of the softmax algorithm but they were really complicated for me and as I said I just started to learn ML and I didn't wanted to use a library off the shelf so here I am.

This is the class I store my activation functions.

```java
public class ActivationFunction {

    public static double tanh(double val) {
        return Math.tanh(val);
    }

    public static double sigmoid(double val) {
        return 1 / 1 + Math.exp(-val);
    }

    public static double relu(double val) {
        return Math.max(val, 0);
    }

    public static double leaky_relu(double val) {
        double result = 0;
        if (val > 0) result = val;
        else result = val * 0.01;
        return result;
    }

    public static double[] softmax(double[] array) {
        double max = max(array);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = array[i] - max;
        }

        double sum = 0;
        double[] result = new double[array.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            sum += Math.exp(array[i]);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            result[i] = Math.exp(array[i]) / sum;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static double dTanh(double x) {
        double tan = Math.tanh(x);
        return (1 / tan) - tan;
    }

    public static double dSigmoid(double x) {
        return x * (1 - x);
    }

    public static double dRelu(double x) {
        double result;
        if (x > 0) result = 1;
        else result = 0;
        return result;
    }

    public static double dLeaky_Relu(double x) {
        double result;
        if (x > 0) result = 1;
        else if (x < 0) result = 0.01;
        else result = 0;
        return result;
    }

    private static double max(double[] array) {
        double result = Double.MIN_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] > result) result = array[i];
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

I am expecting to get the answer for the question: Do I need the derivative of softmax or not?
If so how can I implement it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A short answer to your first question is ***yes***, you need to compute the derivative of softmax.

The longer version will involve some computation since in order to implement backpropagation you train your network by means of first-order optimization algorithm that requires to calculate partial derivatives of the cost function w.r.t the weights, i.e.:

[image]

***However***, since you are using the softmax for your last layer, it is very likely that you are going to optimize a cross-entropy cost function while training your neural network, namely:

[image]

where ***t<sub>j</sub>*** is a target value and ***a<sub>j</sub>*** is a softmax result for class ***j***.

Softmax itself represents a probability distribution over ***n*** classes:

[image]

where all of ***z***'s are simple sums of the result of activation functions of previous layers times the corresponding weights:

[image]

where ***n*** is the number of layer, ***i*** is the number of neuron in the previous layer and ***j*** is the number of neuron in our softmax layer.

So in order to take partial derivatives with respect to any of these weights, one should calculate:

[image]

where second partial derivative ***∂a<sub>k</sub>/∂z<sub>j</sub>*** is indeed the softmax derivative and can be computed in the following way:

[image]

***But*** if you try to compute the aforementioned sum term of the derivative of the cost function w.r.t. the weights, you will get:

[image]
         [image]
         [image]

So in this particular case it turns out that the final result of the computation is quite neat and represents a simple difference between the outputs of the network and the target values, and that's it, i.e., all you need to compute this sum term of partial derivatives is just:

[image]

So to answer your second question, you can combine computation of the partial derivative of the cross-entropy cost function w.r.t output activation (i.e. softmax) together with the partial derivative of the output activation w.r.t. **z<sub>j</sub>** which results in a short and clear implementation, if you are using a non-vectorized form, it will look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lenOfClasses; ++i)
{
    dCdz[i] = t[i] - a[i];
}
```

And subsequently you can use ***dCdz*** for backpropagating to the rest of the layers of the neural network.

Comment: Very well explained. Hats of to you.

Comment: @Michael Glazunov, would you expand the calculations for ∂ak/∂zj with the details? Thanks!